# R Clusteranalysis Ward cluster centers

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I did a cluster analysis in R using euclidean distance and Ward.D2 method in hclust. I want to use these cluster centers as starting point for K-means analysis. But I don't know how to extract the centers for Ward method? Can anybody help please?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a reproducible example using the iris data set:

```
data(iris)
iris.z <- scale(iris[, -5])                            # Standardize the variables
iris.hcl <- hclust(dist(iris.z), method="ward.D2")     # Compute clusters
iris.hcl3 <- cutree(iris.hcl, 3)                       # Cut at 3 clusters
centers <- aggregate(iris.z, by=list(iris.hcl3), mean) # Compute centroids
iris.km3 <- kmeans(iris.z, centers[, -1])              # Compute kmeans
addmargins(xtabs(~iris.hcl3+iris.km3$cluster))         # Compare results
#      iris.km3$cluster
# iris.hcl3   1   2   3 Sum
#       1    49   0   0  49
#       2     1  29   0  30
#       3     0  24  47  71
#       Sum  50  53  47 150
```

Note that 1 row in hcl3 moved from cluster 2 to cluster 1 in the km3 and 24 rows in hcl3 moved from cluster 3 to cluster 2 in km3.

Answer (score 0):

This is also easily achieved using the the `method = "kmeans"` option in [`cluster_analysis`](https://easystats.github.io/parameters/reference/cluster_analysis.html) function from the EasyStats Parameters package.

For example:

```
# Hierarchical k-means (more robust k-means)
if (require("factoextra", quietly = TRUE)) {
  rez <- cluster_analysis(iris[1:4], n = 3, method = "hkmeans")
  rez # Show results
  predict(rez) # Get clusters
}
```